# Seamless experience between website and Salesforce community site - one login?

Tags: community, authentication, oauth, iframe

We have a requirement to allow a seamless experience from our main company website to our Salesforce community site.

Basically, someone can login to our company website and be able to click a link that will open a page in our Salesforce community. Ideally we would not ask them to login to the Salesforce community - they should already be logged in when they login to our company website.

The thought is when someone logs into our company site, we would send for an Oauth token to Salesforce to establish a session with the Salesforce community. Therefore some links on our company site could link to our Salesforce community and the user will already be logged in. We may even want to render our community in an Iframe within a company site page.

Anyone have any ideas how we could build something like this? A way we can programmatically authorize a community user so that they would already be recognized and logged in when directed to a community page, either in a new page load or an Iframe?

We are looking to use Salesforce as the IdP. When a user signs up on our external site, we will be creating community user credentials for them in Salesforce that we want to use as the auth provider.

Thanks

Comment: The broad answer to your question is single sign-on (SSO). oAuth is not SSO. You want OpenID Connect (confusingly built on top of oAuth) or SAML as the SSO protocol (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837553/saml-vs-federated-login-with-oauth) for a good summary of all 3 options). The specific implementation details involve a number of trade-offs between UX/convenience and security of your solution, not something that can be addressed in an answer to a question in a public forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have kinda similar use case and depending on the user data which your external site stores and Salesforce stores. In both cases you will need some backend though.

1. Both your external system and Salesforce instance stores the same username/community user will be auto created

This one is easier.
You'll need to use JWT flow. It can be used without any additional user interaction based only on the username.

2. You have another identifier than username/community users are already existing in Salesforce

This one is slightly more complicated. You'll need to create a logic which will user some other user id than username provided by your external system, and using some integration user authenticate with Salesforce, then search for the community user and again use JWT flow to get access token.

There is another problem though.
Because extended Aura/LWC security you will not be able to easily insert it for example into Iframe. You will need either use vanilla Visualforce or Lightning Out which is in beta as far as I know. Especially if you have some additional communication between community and your external site.

Comment: Once we get an access token using JWT, how to we use it when linking from our external site to the Salesforce community site? Do we need to use something like frontdoor.jsp every time we call a link to our Salesforce community site?

Comment: I'm afraid that yes frontdoor.jsp should be used as in this article https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000332032&type=1 but I'm not 100% sure, maybe there is another way

Comment: Thank you for the help! On the frontdoor.jsp article, it says Community API token is not supported. Is the JWT flow using a different access token? I would think the access token being grabbed using JWT for a community user is the community API token?

Comment: As I understand both of those articles: You can use frontdoor.jsp using Oauth2.0 (JWT) and obtained access_token without any issues (because it is quite secure method of authorization, but you cannot use Session Id from GETSESSIONID() or $Api.Session_ID.